# Merge two projects with different persistence.xml configuration? Use EclipseLink without JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

There are two projects that talk to the same database (but to different tables) in JPA. One with Hibernate (plus some Spring), one with EclipseLink. Projects have to be merged: one must now call the other.

Both have a persistence.xml configuration, but with vendor-specific flags. Merging both persistence.xml has not been successful as you can imagine. Refactoring one project is out of the question.

I was wondering if one could stop relying on JPA (to avoid the persistence.xml conflict) but still get something with Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory, and have that be compatible with annotated `@javax.persistence.Entity`s.

Comment: ... no, because that is all part of the JPA API.

Comment: Why is refactoring out of the question?

Comment: @Gimby yeah, I was telling myself this as I was typing javax.persistence.Entity. However EclipseLink is still code that can be run and process annotated classes. Maybe I'll have to look into how JPA is wiring things together.

Comment: @kaba713 vendor-specific query hints are used on both sides; I'm pretty sure they don't map well.

Comment: _Merging both persistence.xml has not been successful as you can imagine_. Nope, can't imagine why. Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory will look at the JPA providers present, and persistence.xml ...

Comment: @NeilStockton persistence.xml will be processed by only one JPA provider. I need to use both providers in different places.

Comment: Technically it should be feasible with two different persistence units, and you can have as many persistence units within the same persistence.xml as you want. Per persistence unit you can configure the provider. That probably does require a small refactor because all existing PersistenceContext annotations will need to be told which specific unitName to use.

Comment: @Gimby hey you are right, both with NeilStockton. PersistenceProvider s do can be specified in persistence.xml. I think I have been too fixated on limiting the merge being to a single pom.xml dependency. I'll give it a try, and update back.

Comment: To me, your question looks like a "XY problem": You don't really want to use EclipseLink without JPA, you want to merge two projects with differenct JPA configuration. I edited the title accordingly. Feel free to improve it further.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot (easily) "stop relying on JPA". JPA is an API, that is the list of classes and methods that your application uses to talk to the databases. Not using JPA would mean completely rewriting your database layer, which you presumably want to avoid.

However, you can continue using the two `persistence.xml`s side by side (possibly merged into one file). To do this, you would maintain two JPA persistence contexts in parallel, meaning you would have two different `EntityManagerFactory`s in your code for the different parts of your (merged) application.

This will sometimes make life a bit more complicated, because things like Spring integration of JPA usually assume there is only one persistence context, but it should be doable.

While your case seems rather unique, one common reason to have multiple persistence contexts in parallel is when you need to access multiple databases from one application. See for example [persistence.xml for multiple persistence units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275676/persistence-xml-for-multiple-persistence-units) for how this can work.

In principle, this will also work if the two persistence contexts access the same database. You'll just need to be careful with caching in JPA, because that usually assumes noone else is writing to the database. However, if your two persistence contexts never operate on the same table, that should be no problem.

---

Try using two persistence units in parallel, and if you get stuck, ask a new question :-).